# category<->product relations

Tags: magento, categories, product, relation

I have this problem with magento 1.4.1.1, when I delete a product it won't decrease the amount of products in the category tree view. I found out that magento is not deleting the entry from the "catalog_category_product" table.

Can anyone think of a reason why this is happening? I'm trying to search the core where this function is being called (removing that row from the db) but I can't find it.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh the Index (System > Index Management) and all should be set